# Node.js Express API "Cannot GET" with all routes. Works on localhost but not my server

Tags: node.js, express

My current code is:

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/api')
});

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        text: 'my api!'
    })
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('App listening on ' + port + '!');
});
```

The above code works as intended on localhost but when deployed onto the server I'm using, I get the following error:

> Cannot GET /api
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

Comment: did you use correct port ?

Comment: @xMayank in the code or the request? If I use port 3000 in the request it times out, without any port in the code I get the same result as mentioned in the original post

Comment: What is different between your dev box and the server? Is the server running another web server? Have you checked to see what ports are in use on the server?

Comment: Is there a firewall or something else listening on that device/port? You can't listen on localhost for your app.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work on any server you will have to define your port.

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/api')
});

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        text: 'my api!'
    })
});

//You can bind the IP address using the following code
app.listen(port, '<ip>', function () {
    console.log('App listening on ' + port + '!');
});
```

As I can see in your code you can access server it is on `3000`

or if you have `.env`

You have to explicitly define your port number

```
PORT=80 //this may change depending on your choice
```

then access your server `http://<address>:port`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen(port, <your public ip>, () => {
   console.log('App listening on ' + port + '!'); 
});
```

Comment: Can u make sure that the port is exposed in the server

Comment: I created an environment variable "PORT" and set it to 3000, I am then using process.env.PORT as a parameter in the app.listen() call

Comment: Code only answers are vastly improved by adding an explanation of how and why they work. In this case you are asking for more information, not providing an answer, so using the comment feature would be more appropriate than posting this as an answer.

Comment: is this a remote server? if yes then make sure you have exposed the port. If the error still persists make sure that the ip is a pubic ip (in case of an ec2 remote server use the elastic ip)